# Do indicator functions form a basis for the closed subspace of measurable functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

I recently learned the orthagonal projection interpretation of the conditional expectation, where $\mathbb{E}(X | \mathcal{A})$ is the orthagonal projection of $X$ onto the linear subspace of $\mathcal{A}$-measurable square-integrable functions.

This got me to thinking, do the indicator functions $\mathbb{1}_A$ for $A \in \mathcal{A}$ form a basis of this subspace, since any such measurable function is the limit of the sum of such step functions? And does an orthagonal basis exist?

Comment: 1. AFAIK, any measurable function can be approximated by indicators only *pointwise*, but not necessarily in $L^2$, so indicators may not be enough. 2. Anyways, you have a Hilbert space - so the orthogonal basis always exists

Comment: $1_{A \cup B} = 1_A + 1_B - 1_{A \cap B}$, so these are not linearly independent.

Comment: @Ilya You do have that they approximate in $L^2$, otherwise the whole idea of defining integrals as the monotone limit of approximations by simple functions wouldn't work, no? It might be though that you loose this property if you pick *one* *orthogonal* set of indicator functions for *every* $f$, since in the integral definition you're ranging over *all* approximations for every *particular* f.

Comment: @fgp: perhaps, you are right, but I can't see immediately that indicators form a complete system. Suppose, $f$ is a positive $L^2$ function and $f_n$ are positive simple function that monotonically and pointwise converge to $f$. We have that
$$
  \lim \int f_n = \int f \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \lim \int (f-f_n) = 0,
$$
however I don't see how can it imply that
$$
  \lim\int (f-f_n)^2 = 0
$$